# How to change Nxt/Ardor wallet settings to keep the account ledger table untrimmed?

Tags: nxt, ardor

For purposes of extracting all transactions of an Nxt/Ardor account, it would be very useful to export the **complete** account ledger table.
Is it then enough to just set nxt.ledgerTrimKeep=0 and nxt.ledgerAccount=ARDR-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx (the account ID in RS format) in nxt.properties or are there other settings to be changed?

How do you initiate a re-scan to generate the whole ledger table afterwards? The database re-downloading would also be an option here, however, would take more time I guess.

A good use for this would be to import the ledger table into a tool for computing taxes resulting from crypto transaction profits, e.g. CoinTracking.info.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a full ledger for a specific account set the following nxt.properties:

```
# Do not trim the ledger
nxt.ledgerTrimKeep=0

# Only log these specific accounts
nxt.ledgerAccounts=NXT-V4D7-D3XW-JX9Z-EAC8K;NXT-XK4R-7VJU-6EQG-7R335
```

To rebuild the ledger, invoke the `scan` API with parameter `height` set to 0.
This operation can run for several hours depending on your configuration.